# Selenium-2 Webdriver browser support

Tags: selenium, selenium2

I have a question about selenium2 (webdriver).

As selenium-2 supports following 4 types of web drivers..

1-IE

2-firefox

3-chrome

4-htmlunit

Is there any way to use any other webdriver apart from these; like Safari, Opera etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/enmbgeQRmJ8) discussion might help

In case link perishes on internet -

> > Selenium 2.0 supports.
> > chrome
> > 12.0.712.0+
> > IE
> > 6, 7, 8, 9 - 32 and 64-bit where applicable
> > Firefox
> > 3.0, 3.5, 3.6, 4.0, 5.0 (most subject to change)
> > Opera
> > 11.5+
> > Also:
> > HtmlUnit 2.8
> > Android 2.3+ on devices (emulators broken at the moment)
> > I'm not sure which iOS versions we support We also support any browser 1.0 supports through the
> > SeleniumBackedWebDriver, but there will probably be issues

Comment: Thanks Tarun for quick response, But I am not able to open this link, Please check..

Comment: I have copied link here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/enmbgeQRmJ8

Comment: I am sorry Tarun, but still I am not abel to open htttp://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/enmbgeQRmJ8 see "#!topic"

Comment: I am able to open the link in the answer and the link in the comment.

Comment: Thanks @ Tarun Bhadauria, I think this is because of fire-wall setting in my office, I will check this link outside.. +1